# SSH key but for git access only

Tags: git, ssh

I have a git repository on an ubuntu server where my team and I contribute code. I usually give each memeber access to the repository using an ssh key. The problem is they can use the key to login to the server. 
I would like to set up some ssh keys that can only be used to perform git operations, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have many users or don't want to move to a new management system (gitolite etc), you can use git's own [git-shell](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell).

You can set up a git user whose shell doesn't do anything. They can still use the server to push pull from git but can't do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use a git management system like [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

With Gitolite you use give access only to the repository with read and write access. Bitbucket is the same but an external service. The difference to Github is that its mainly for private repositories.